# thread flag to stop others and multi-tread collision

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have the following code (I removed some irrelevant parts)

With this code I can make the threads from "connect_ip" don't start again but the current ones are still running and I would like to stop them too (only those in "connect_ip")

```
struct domain_list {
    char domain[20];
    struct domain_list * next;
};
typedef struct arg_struct {
    unsigned long ip;
    char domain[30];
    int X;
    int stop;
}arg_struct;
struct domain_list * first_domain = NULL;

int main()
{
    //loading into structure from file code is missing


    for(i = 0 ; i < number_thread; i++)
    {
        if(pthread_create(&thread_id[i],NULL,&start,NULL) != 0)
        {
            i--;
            fprintf(stderr,RED "\nError in creating thread\n" NONE);
        }
    }
    for(i = 0 ; i < number_thread; i++)
        if(pthread_join(thread_id[i],NULL) != 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,RED "\nError in joining thread\n" NONE);
        }
}


void * start(void * data)
{
    unsigned long ip = 0xffffffff;
    char ip[20];
    while (!feof(INFILE))
    {
        if (fgets(ip,sizeof(ip),INFILE) != NULL)
        {
            if (strlen(ip) < 8)
                break;
            if (ip[strlen (ip) - 1] == '\n')
                ip[strlen (ip) - 1] = '\0';
            ip = ntohl((unsigned long)inet_addr(ip));
        }
        connect_ip(ip);
    }
    return NULL;
}


void connect_ip(unsigned long ip)
{
    struct domain_list * curr_domain = first_domain;
    int exit=0,stop=0;
    while(curr_domain)
    {
        for(t = 0 ; t < ip_thread; t++)
        {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&thrd_list);
            arg_struct *args = calloc(1, sizeof(*args));
            strncpy(args->domain,curr_domain->domain,sizeof(args->domain) - 1);
            args->ip = ip;
            args->X = ex;
            args->stop = stop;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&thrd_list);
            if(pthread_create(&thread_id[t],NULL,checkip,args) != 0)
            {
                t--;
                fprintf(stderr,RED "\nError in creating thread\n" NONE);
            }
            else
            {
                pthread_mutex_lock(&thrd_list);
                if(curr_domain->next != NULL)
                    curr_domain = curr_domain->next;
                else
                    exit = 1;
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&thrd_list);
            }
        }

        for(t = 0 ; t < ip_thread; t++)
        {
            void *join_result;
            if(pthread_join(thread_id[t],&join_result) != 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr,RED "\nError in joining thread\n" NONE);
            }
            else
            {
                arg_struct *args = join_result;
                stop = args->stop;
                free(args);
            }
        }
        if (exit == 1 || stop == 1)
            break;
    }//end while

}

void *checkip(void *arguments)
{
    arg_struct *args = arguments;
    if (args->X == 1)
        return args;
    int sock = 0,ex = 0,ret = 0;
    struct in_addr t_in;
    t_in.s_addr = ntohl(args->ip);
    sock = check_port(args->ip,80);
    if(sock == -1)
    {
        args->X = 1;
        return args;
    }

//some code missing

    if(ret == 1)
        args->stop = 1;
    return args;
}
```

First question is how to make all threads from "connect_ip" stop when ret = 1 in void "checkip" and not affect the other threads from "start" void?

Second question is how to use correctly pthread_mutex_lock in this case so the threads from "start" and those from "connect_ip" to mess up the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two quick observations. First, why are you doing this in the for-loop: "i--;". Due to this, the thread identifiers might sit in different indices in the thread_id array. Second, same thign with "t--;" in the connect_ip() function. This might be leading to pthread_join() refer to incorrect thread ids when doing the pthread_join().

Please look for additional text in comments.

Adding a quick example that allows individual connect_Ip threads to maintain a common signal variable among its child thread. The example artificially sets the global variable for connect_ip thread with index 1. This way, all the (three) child threads of connect_ip thread stop once the signal is set. On the other hand, the other parent thread (connect_ip with index 0) continues to run:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define TEMP_MAX_THREADS 2
#define TEMP_MAX_CHILD_THREADS 3

int stop[TEMP_MAX_THREADS];

typedef struct two_ints_ {
    int parent_index;
    int child_index;
    int *common_stop_all_children;
} two_ints;

void *check_ip (void *arg) {
    int i = 0, temp;
    two_ints *x = (two_ints *)arg;
    printf("\t%s Starting to run (index: %d parent: %d) \n",
            __FUNCTION__, x->child_index, x->parent_index);
    srand(time(NULL));
    while (i++ < 10){
        printf("\t%s Me wokeup (index: %d parent: %d) \n",
                __FUNCTION__, x->child_index, x->parent_index);
        sleep(1);
        if (x->parent_index == 1) {
            if (*(x->common_stop_all_children) == 1) {
                printf("\t%s Other thread has set the stop signal (index: %d parent: %d). Return\n",
                        __FUNCTION__, x->child_index, x->parent_index);
                return;
            }
            temp = rand() % 4;
            if (temp == 2) {
                printf("\t%s Time to return. Let us set the global stop to 1 (index: %d parent: %d) \n",
                        __FUNCTION__, x->child_index, x->parent_index);
                *(x->common_stop_all_children) = 1;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

void *connect_ip (void *arg) {
    int common_stop_all_children = 0;
    pthread_t child_thread_id[TEMP_MAX_CHILD_THREADS];
    two_ints arg_two_ints[TEMP_MAX_CHILD_THREADS];
    int i;

    printf("I am here with index: %d \n", *(int *)arg);
    for(i = 0 ; i < TEMP_MAX_CHILD_THREADS; i++) {
        arg_two_ints[i].parent_index = *(int *)arg;
        arg_two_ints[i].child_index = i;
        arg_two_ints[i].common_stop_all_children = &common_stop_all_children;

        if(pthread_create(&child_thread_id[i], NULL, check_ip, (void*) &arg_two_ints[i]) != 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "\nError in creating thread\n" );
        }
    }

    for(i = 0 ; i < TEMP_MAX_CHILD_THREADS; i++) {
        if(pthread_join(child_thread_id[i], NULL) != 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "\npthread_join failed\n" );
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    pthread_t thread_id[TEMP_MAX_THREADS];
    int index[TEMP_MAX_THREADS];
    int i;

    for(i = 0 ; i < TEMP_MAX_THREADS; i++) {
        index[i] = i;
        if(pthread_create(&thread_id[i], NULL, connect_ip, (void *)&index[i]) != 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "\nError in creating thread\n" );
        }
    }

    for(i = 0 ; i < TEMP_MAX_THREADS; i++) {
        if(pthread_join(thread_id[i], NULL) != 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "\npthread_join failed\n");
        }
    }

}
```

Here is a sample output.

```
$ ./a.out
I am here with index: 1
I am here with index: 0
    check_ip Starting to run (index: 0 parent: 1)
    check_ip Starting to run (index: 1 parent: 1)
    check_ip Me wokeup (index: 0 parent: 1)
    check_ip Starting to run (index: 0 parent: 0)
    check_ip Starting to run (index: 2 parent: 1)
    check_ip Me wokeup (index: 1 parent: 1)
    check_ip Starting to run (index: 1 parent: 0)
    check_ip Starting to run (index: 2 parent: 0)
    check_ip Me wokeup (index: 0 parent: 0)
    check_ip Me wokeup (index: 2 parent: 1)
    check_ip Me wokeup (index: 1 parent: 0)
    check_ip Me wokeup (index: 2 parent: 0)
    check_ip Me wokeup (index: 2 parent: 1)
    check_ip Me wokeup (index: 0 parent: 0)
    check_ip Time to return. Let us set the global stop to 1 (index: 1 parent: 1)
    check_ip Me wokeup (index: 1 parent: 0)
    check_ip Me wokeup (index: 2 parent: 0)
    check_ip Me wokeup (index: 0 parent: 1)
    check_ip Me wokeup (index: 2 parent: 0)
    check_ip Other thread has set the stop signal (index: 2 parent: 1). Return
    check_ip Me wokeup (index: 0 parent: 0)
    check_ip Me wokeup (index: 1 parent: 0)
    check_ip Other thread has set the stop signal (index: 0 parent: 1). Return
    check_ip Me wokeup (index: 2 parent: 0)
    check_ip Me wokeup (index: 0 parent: 0)
    check_ip Me wokeup (index: 1 parent: 0)
    check_ip Me wokeup (index: 1 parent: 0)
    check_ip Me wokeup (index: 0 parent: 0)
    check_ip Me wokeup (index: 2 parent: 0)
    check_ip Me wokeup (index: 2 parent: 0)
    check_ip Me wokeup (index: 1 parent: 0)
    check_ip Me wokeup (index: 0 parent: 0)
    check_ip Me wokeup (index: 2 parent: 0)
    check_ip Me wokeup (index: 0 parent: 0)
    check_ip Me wokeup (index: 1 parent: 0)
    check_ip Me wokeup (index: 2 parent: 0)
    check_ip Me wokeup (index: 1 parent: 0)
    check_ip Me wokeup (index: 0 parent: 0)
^C
```

Comment: it's not about cleaning resources. in void "checkip" I have a long loop from another struct and when the record is found, it exits the loop and returns ret = 1, so all the other threads from connect_ip (same ip, different socket) must stop even if they run atm

Comment: so there must be some flag which will trigger the other threads to stop. I did that already but the flag triggered all threads to stop not only those from connect_ip, so it was useless

Comment: Well, if the threads created from connect_ip return and the caller thread from conenct_ip does not have anythign else to do, then only that (connect_ip) thread should return and not others. Can you please show the code with the flag. Also, can you please remove the "i--" and "t--" since they might be affecting pthread_join() calls.

Comment: I don't think they affect pthread_join calls ... With i-- & t-- in the array there will be only started threads. But anyways, that's not the question. As I said, the program is working fine except the issue I described in my post

Comment: You probably need to show the code with flag. Since threads shared hte same memory, you probably might want to put flags in another array (similar to thread_id array). Let me explain it. If you two thread from main: t1 and t2. And t1 has two child threads (for checkip): t11, t12 and t2 also has two child threads: t21, t22. Now, if you set the flag globally with t11, then t12 would return, but so would t21 and t22. Is that something  you might be running into?

Comment: yes. if t22 returned ret 1, I want to automatically stop t21, but the others to continue their work.

Comment: and yes, I tried with a global flag and it didn't work exactly as I expected

Comment: Yeah, so the global flag is visible to all threads. You could use args->stop field to do that. Make all args->stop point to a common  stop value in a stop_array for that connect_ip thread. You could do "args->stop = &stop_id[i];" and declare stop as "int *stop" in arg_struct. This way, if any thread updates the value of stop, they would actually update one common stop value and that would be visible to all child threads of a given connect_ip() parent thread.

Comment: We should keep in mind that threads share the same memory and using an array index per connect_ip() thread would be a workable idea to communicate between threads spawned by the parent connect_ip() thread.

Comment: I have added a quick example code that does this. I have added that in my answer. It shows how a parent thread (connect_ip) can maintain a common info for its own child threads.

Comment: thanks for your answer but I think there is one problem: I pass different struct data every time to checkip with calloc. I use args not &args. And unfortunately cannot change that because I need it this way.

Comment: That should not be a problem. Simply add "int *common_stop_all_children;" to your arg_struct and make it point to the address of the common variable int common_stop_all_children = 0;. Please note that each thread gets its own stack so this address would be unique to all the child threads. Btw, the example is just to show how one can achieve this -- of course, you will have to tweak it for your example.